# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 cannot create new maven module?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have just updated my IntelliJ IDEA to 2017.3 but I cannot seem to insert new Maven module? When I try to insert it nothing happens at all. I have opened idea.txt log and found this:

```
2017-12-01 11:25:28,464 [ 551502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3  Build #IU-173.3727.127 
2017-12-01 11:25:28,464 [ 551502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2017-12-01 11:25:28,464 [ 551502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017-12-01 11:25:28,464 [ 551502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2017-12-01 11:25:28,464 [ 551502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2017-12-01 11:25:28,464 [ 551502]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: NewModuleInGroup 
2017-12-01 11:25:38,059 [ 561097]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1 
2017-12-01 11:26:42,204 [ 625242]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/settings/GradleProjectSettings 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/settings/GradleProjectSettings
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.AbstractExtensionPointBean.findClass(AbstractExtensionPointBean.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.AbstractExtensionPointBean.instantiate(AbstractExtensionPointBean.java:63)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilderFactory.createBuilder(ModuleBuilderFactory.java:32)
    at com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder.getAllBuilders(ModuleBuilder.java:74)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.ProjectTypeStep.a(ProjectTypeStep.java:279)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.ProjectTypeStep.<init>(ProjectTypeStep.java:117)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.NewProjectWizard.init(NewProjectWizard.java:50)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectWizard.NewProjectWizard.<init>(NewProjectWizard.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.actions.NewModuleAction.actionPerformed(NewModuleAction.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.a(ActionMenuItem.java:321)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:911)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:311)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.a(ActionMenuItem.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.a(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.a(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:130)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.a(BegMenuItemUI.java:521)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:48)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:541)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.h(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.settings.GradleProjectSettings PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.kotlin, 1.2.0-release-IJ2017.3-1] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@6e1fc42d
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 61 more
```

It seems like there is an issue with Gradle classes missing, but I don't use Gradle at all in any of my projects. What should I do?

Comment: There was an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21236) with Kotlin plugin. Will be fixed with the soon version update. In the meantime the workaround is to either Enable Gradle plugin or disable Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Disabling the kotlin plugin helped. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it and close it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21236) with Kotlin plugin. Will be fixed with the soon version update. In the meantime the workaround is to either Enable Gradle plugin or disable Kotlin plugin.